# Как передать одинаковые названия параметров в get запросе PHP YII2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii

делаю блог в учебных целях. Пытаюсь настроить фильтрацию постов по тегам, передавая в урл id тегов. Нагуглил, что можно к параметру приписать [], чтобы значения не переписывали друг друга, но в урле скобки преобразовываются в %5B0%5D. Как можно этого избежать, и есть ли более правильные/лучшие варианты решения этой проблемы?

Comment: А что не так с преобразованием скобок в урле? Это никак не должно вам мешать.

Comment: Экстрасенсы в отпуске, код в студию.

Comment: У меня есть несколько категорий(и ссылок для них). Я прикрутил pjax и фильтрую по get параметру посты через эти категории.Я нажимаю на ссылку у которой ?category=1 (она конечно, добавляется в урл) , потом я нажимаю на ссылку ?category=2 (она перезатирает ?category=1) и т.д. Мне нужно, чтобы они отображались одновременно, а при клике на уже выбранную категорию, она убиралась

Comment: Как с помощью pjax отправить гет запросы через чекбокс?